# Excel VBA error: Invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a VB script in excel to convert the file into a CSV file and I am getting Invalid procedure call or argument error. Not aware how to resolve this error/

I have tried cleaning the data and running the script in smaller pieces. Not able to resolve the error/

```
Sub WRITE_BOM()
Set objworksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BOM")
output_path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")
Set myfileFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
output_file_name = "BOM" & ".txt"
Set myts = myfileFSO.CreateTextFile(output_path & "\" & output_file_name)

introw = 1
Count = 0
Do Until objworksheet.Cells(introw, 1).Value = ""
Count = Count + 1
introw = introw + 1
Loop
For i = 2 To Count

If i = 2 Then

myts.write "E;" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 1).Value & ";" & 
objworksheet.Cells(i, 2).Value & ";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 3) & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 4).Value & ";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 5).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 6).Value & 
";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 7).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 8).Value & 
";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 9).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 10).Value 
& ";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 11).Value & Chr(13) & Chr(10) _
& "L;" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 12).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 
13).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 14).Value & ";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 15).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 16).Value 
& ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 17).Value & ";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 18).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 19).Value 
& ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 20).Value & ";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 21).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 22).Value 
& ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 23).Value & ";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 24).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 25).Value 
& ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 26).Value & ";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 27).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 28).Value 
& ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 29) & Chr(13) & Chr(10)

End If

If i > 2 Then

If objworksheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = objworksheet.Cells((i - 1), 1).Value 
Then

myts.write "L;" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 12).Value & ";" & 
objworksheet.Cells(i, 13).Value & ";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 14).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 15).Value 
& ";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 16).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 17).Value 
& ";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 18).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 19).Value 
& ";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 20).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 21).Value 
& ";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 22).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 23).Value 
& ";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 24).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 25).Value 
& ";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 26).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 27).Value 
& ";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 28).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 29) & 
Chr(13) & Chr(10)

Else

myts.write "E;" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 1).Value & ";" & 
objworksheet.Cells(i, 2).Value & ";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 3) & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 4).Value & ";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 5).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 6).Value & 
";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 7).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 8).Value & 
";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 9).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 10).Value 
& ";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 11).Value & Chr(13) & Chr(10) _
& "L;" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 12).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 
13).Value & ";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 14).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 15).Value 
& ";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 16).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 17).Value 
& ";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 18).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 19).Value 
& ";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 20).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 21).Value 
& ";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 22).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 23).Value 
& ";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 24).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 25).Value 
& ";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 26).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 27).Value 
& ";" _
& objworksheet.Cells(i, 28).Value & ";" & objworksheet.Cells(i, 29) & 
Chr(13) & Chr(10)

End If

End If

Next

' msgbox "Done."
End Sub
```

What could I be missing? I am running this script locally inside Excel.

Comment: just correct "breaking  single code Statements into multiple lines" rules and it is working. Refrained from answering as you yourself may look out for lines ending without _  and correct the problem . Other issues are, may use `Count = objworksheet.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row` instead of `Do Until objworksheet.Cells(introw, 1).Value = ""` loop. If branches could be restructured and instead of concatenating code lines simple loops can be created.

Comment: Note: VBA and vbscript are *not* the same. If code is within an application then it's VBA, and only VBA. Please be careful when tagging and read the tag information.